# how to pass "None" parameter value using XmlRpc.NET?

Tags: xml-rpc

I am trying to use XmlRpc.NET to call a method with following signature (the server is built with Python):

```
boolean wiki.deletePage(string name, int version=None)
```

The problem is, how do I pass "None" to the method? I tried to use "int?" in C# and pass null but XmlRpc.NET will throw exception for the second parameter being null; passing "0" will not be correct as the server can only do some special handling when the parameter is None.

Thanks

Comment: XML-RPC doesn't strictly have a NULL or None value: http://www.xmlrpc.com/

Some times it is represented by using an empty list, but this is implementation specific. Particular libraries also may have extensions that allow sending and receiving NULL values, but again, it is implementation specific and might not work between arbitrary pairs of client/server libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently working on a new release of XML-RPC.NET which will have support for . I'm aiming to get it ready by the end of the year. In the scenario you describe, the parameter would be defined as int? as you already tried.